# /bin/find : Argument list too long

Tags: unix

I am a beginner programming shell scripts, right now I am doing a shell script to create zip files according to last modification of directory inside a path. Where date is:

today=`date +%Y-%m-%d`

customers=`find /DOMINOAPP/Delta_Transfer/*/* -type d -name "*" -newermt $today | cut -d "/" -f4`

I got this error:

> ./zips.sh: line 8: /bin/find: Argument list too long

Please anyone could you help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards (outside of strings) are expanded by the shell, so here `/DOMINOAPP/Delta_Transfer/*/*` is *first* expanded by the shell, *then* passed to `find`. If it contains a lot of files the list will be super long and you’ll get that error.

`find` already goes into all subdirectories, so you can remove those wildcards:

```
find /DOMINOAPP/Delta_Transfer -type d -name "*" -newermt $today
```

---

To better understand wildcard expansion by the shell, compare the following commands:

```
$ touch a1 a2 a3
$ echo a*    # <-- expansion, = 'echo a1 a2 a3'
a1 a2 a3
$ echo "a*"  # <-- no expansion, = 'echo a*'
a*
```